# Android: Display variable image

Tags: android, image, variables, imageview

EDIT. I try to load variable image but somehow its not working. I think i have wrong xml imageview setup.

```
ImageView lblPic = new ImageView(this);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(pic, "drawable", getPackageName());
lblPic.setImageResource(resID);
```

xml imageview
    
Using xml like this i hoped that code in Java will replace android:src defined image but it doesnt. If im not using android:src it cause error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the name of the pictures, you need to do

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

where `filename` is the part that comes AFTER `R.drawable.`, and then call

```
lblPic.setImageResource(resId);
```

Comment: Do i have to make imageview in xml file or it can work without it?

Comment: you can create the imageview in code if you need to. i prefer to do it in xml. it keeps your code cleaner and it is easier to set some properties in xml than in code. use `(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewIdFromXML)` to get the imageview if you define it in xml